# Is this iam json policy the same in terraform?

Tags: json, terraform, amazon-iam

I have this json template file that I would like to convert into `data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example"` and im not sure if i'm converting the json correctly

JSON template im trying to convert (iam-file.json):

```
"Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:logs:arn": "arn:aws:logs:${region}:${account_id}:*"
                }
            }
```

What i've done so far in iam.tf:

```
condition {
      test = "ArnLike"
      values = [
        "arn:aws:logs:${var.region}:${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:*"
      ]
      variable = "kms:EncryptionContext:arn:aws:logs"
    }
```

Are they both the same thing? Im not sure on how the `variable` works in the `iam.tf`
When i try to plan-apply these changes i get this:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
  ~ update in-place

~ Condition = {
                 ~ ArnLike = {
                              + kms:EncryptionContext:arn:aws:logs = [
                                  + "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:123456789:*",
                                ]
                 - kms:EncryptionContext:aws:logs:arn = "arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:123456789:*" -> null
                            }
```

Comment: They should be.

Comment: That modifies a string to a list of one string. Whether that is the same or not depends on AWS IAM schema, and in general the IAM schema considers a string and a list of one string element to be equivalent.